# Javascript push object and count in foreach loop

Tags: jquery, loops, object, foreach

i'm working on a .forEach loop of users in jQuery
and i want to create an object array of the user groups to use for something else. rather then pull the data in for all users again for the function

here is my example below

```js
   var data = [
                    {
                            "user_id": '1',
                            "username": "test2",
                            "email": "test@test.com",
                            "access_type": "admin"
                    },
                    {
                            "user_id": '2',
                            "username": "test2",
                            "email": "test2@test2.com",
                            "access_type": "admin"
                    },                    {
                            "user_id": '3',
                            "username": "test3",
                            "email": "test3@test3.com",
                            "access_type": "user"
                    }
                ];


      var users_select = {};

   data.forEach(function(i){
      
    var type = i.access_type;
    var setup = users_select;
                var fullcount = setup.type.typecount;
    if(fullcount !== undefined){
     fullcount =  fullcount + 1;
    } else {
     setup[type] = {'name':type,'typecount':0};
    }

      });

      console.log(users_select);
```

```html
 //example of data for the for each loop
```

i get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'typecount' of undefined"
the if statement should be enough to setup the object

the desired output should look like this

```js
{ admin: {
    name: "admin",
    typecount: 2
  },
  user: {
    name: "admin",
    typecount: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: `setup.type.typecount` is going to be a null pointer exception the first time through the loop

Comment: Also `type` in that format is a literal, not a variable

Comment: `if (setup[type]) { ++setup[type].typecount; } else { setup[type] = {name: type, typecount: 0}; }` to address both problems above.

Comment: thank you @T.J.Crowder that worked perfect also i had to change typecount: 0 to 1 because it if its going to else its already 1,

thank you so much.

Comment: @c.naka - Doh! Of course. :-) Glad that helped!